# Swagger documentation for wcf api

Tags: c#, wcf, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a wcf api project which is already created. but I want to implement swagger documentation of all api's methods.

I am using Swagger4WCF to generate the yaml file by performing the steps given in
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1190441/How-to-generate-basic-swagger-yaml-description-for

But I am not able to generate the yaml file because there are some api methods which have return type like DataSet. As I can not change the datatype because this is previously created api and being used somewhere else.

Can anybody suggest me, how I can generate the swagger documentation for those method as well.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public DataSet GetData(int value)
    {
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        return dataset;
        //return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}


public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public DataSet GetData(int value)
    {
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        return dataset;
        //return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command ""mypath\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testSwgger\packages\Swagger4WCF.1.0.0\build\Swagger4WCF.exe" "mypath\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testSwgger\testSwgger.sln" "mypath\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testSwgger\testSwgger\testSwgger.csproj" "Debug" "AnyCPU" "mypath\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testSwgger\testSwgger\bin\testSwgger.dll"" exited with code -532462766.  testSwgger

Answer (score 0):

There were some throwing error exceptions in the project [Swagger4WCF](https://github.com/Virtuoze/Swagger4WCF/pull/2). I have fixed them. I hope you cannot see them again. There is a new version of nuget-package in [nuget.org.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger4WCF/1.0.1) You could install it and check

Comment: Thank you @Larissa for your answer I will try it again.